# Hot disable change user in django admin

Tags: django

How I can disable to change the user in my model. Only view. Thnx for Help

This my code

```
class Item(models.Model):
"""Item Model"""
title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=200)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
category = TreeForeignKey(
    Category,
    verbose_name="Category",
    related_name='items',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
version = models.CharField("Version", max_length=10, help_text="v4.5 or 4.5-2")
upload = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
description = HTMLField()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKNd0.png

Comment: Add you model and and please try to be more specific because this is no the right way to ask question you have to put you code here

Comment: ok I'm understand, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions. 
1.
add `editable=False`
example: 
`user = models.OneToOneField(User, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
2. in admin.py add `readonly_fields=['user']` example:

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user',]
    readonly_fields = ['user', ]
```

Make sure to use `py manage.py makemigrations` and then `py manage.py migrate`